# Duplicating a char in a string, leaves an empty string

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have this very simple code witch leaves me with an empty string. As you can see it simply duplicates every '\' in the 'FileDir' string. When I call 'Showmessage(FileDir)', I get an empty box. However, when I call 'Showmessage(FileDir[I])' in my loop I do get the char.

```
var
  s, FileDir: string;
  I: integer;

for I := 0 to FileDir.Length do
begin
  if FileDir[I] = '\' then
    s := s + '\';
  s := s + FileDir[i];
end;
FileDir := s;
Showmessage(FileDir);
```

I have edited my code to put the string in an editbox and then copy it into my 'FileDir' string. This works, but I'm not satisfied

```
for I := 0 to FileDir.Length do
begin
  if FileDir[I] = '\' then
    edbox.Text := edbox.Text + '\';
  edbox.Text := edbox.Text + FileDir[i];
end;
FileDir := edbox.Text;
Showmessage(FileDir);
```

It's probable I dont see the obvious, so maybe one of you does. Thanks in advance

Comment: FileDir.Length-1 perhaps, or start from 1 depending on the value of Low(String).

Comment: @Eszee LURD offered two suggestions, not one, and please don't say "doesn't work", please be precise.

Comment: You could make the loop zbs-agnostic by looping from Low(FileDir) to High(FileDir).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for I := 0 to FileDir.Length do
```

Here you iterate over `FileDir.Length+1` characters which is clearly not your intention. If you are using zero based strings the loop should be

```
for I := 0 to FileDir.Length-1 do
```

Or if your strings are one based then it should be

```
for I := 1 to FileDir.Length do
```

> When I call 'Showmessage(FileDir)', I get an empty box.

This would seem to indicate that the out-of-bounds access is when you access element with index zero, so it seems that your strings are traditional one based strings.

---

The real moral of the tale is that you need to enable range checking in your compiler options. Once you do that the compiler will emit diagnostics code that will throw an informative runtime error whenever you perform out-of-bounds array access.

---

Your code could all be replaced by

```
FileDir := StringReplace(FileDir, '\', '\\', rfReplaceAll);
```

Comment: Thats it, thank you. Can you explain a bit what a one base string is?

Comment: Never mind. I think I got it from your edited answer

Comment: With the advent of the mobile compilers, the language designers at Embarcadero have decided to try to address the inconsistency that Delphi strings are one based (first element has index 1) whereas dynamic arrays are zero based (first element has index 0). The mobile compilers use zero based strings. The desktop compilers default to one based strings but can be switched in to a zero based mode. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_iOS_from_Desktop#Use_0-Based_Strings